# I use react router version 5 , and get error, its not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use react-router-dom version 5 but it's not working. It get me an error

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/users/:id" children={<User />} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you've correctly installed `react-router-dom`? From the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom` to see what is actually installed.

Comment: It looks like you're using a pre-hooks version. Looks like hooks were added in [v5.1.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0).